# qBittorrent - and possible Asus RT-N66U port forwarding

Tags: windows-8, router, port-forwarding, bittorrent

I've recently reformatted my computer and re-installed Windows 8.1 (as it's the only version I have on hand at the moment) but am experiencing some shoddy upload speeds from my torrent client, qBittorrent 3.3.12.

Without going into to much detail of what I've already tried, I've tried calling Asus (which was meaningless), visit PortForward.com which have an outdated guide for my forwarding needs, and Googled quite a bit.

It should also be noted that I'm not using a VPN of any kind as all my torrenting is legitimate in accordance with my countries law.

Now I believe a picture says more than a thousand words, so I'll be illustrating as much as I can visually from here on out (don't mind the stupid black theme, it's something a friend of mine insists on using).

What raised the alarms was the following:

[image]

That little yellow R at the bottom of qBittorent indicates that there's something wrong with my connection.

Windows Firewall is disabled for the duration of my testing from Services:

[image]

Windows Defender is off:

[image]

I've set up a nice static IP (if this is something I should be blurring out or is somehow not something I should post online, please tell me):

-image of static IP cut for privacy reasons-

I chose a nice high port number for qBittorrent to operate on (which someone just told me was good practice):

[image]

(**Sidenote**: all other settings are the default in qBittorrent)

I then went on to check if this port was open with the following online tools:

```
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
http://portchecker.co/check
http://canyouseeme.org/
```

They all told me that my port, 60990, was closed. (**Sidenote**: they all focused on some "Remote Address" which is NOT the static IP I set up. Should it be? I don't recognize the IP they're pointing to at all...)

So I headed over to my router, logged in, and found the "Virtual Server / Port Forwarding" section. There I (which before you ask has the latest firmware) found "BitTorrent" under "Famous games" (don't know why it's called a game, but whatever), added it, applied, then rebooted my PC. The router's screen looked like this:

-image cut for privacy reasons-

No change, little qBittorrent R-icon is still yellow. All the above-mentioned port-checkers all argue my port still closed.

Then I got a little creative and added this, thinking that would solve my problem:

-image cut for privacy reasons-

(**Sidenote**: at this point I'm just improvising not really knowing what I was doing or if it would help. I might be taking steps backwards for all I knew.)

I ran my sweet port 60990 through all the sites again, only for them to tell me it's closed and flag me red.

And that's about where I am now.

I have tried everything in my power to open a port for qBittorrent to get through but I've exhausted every shred of knowledge available to me.

What am I missing here?

What do I need to do to open a port for qBittorrent to use?

If you need any other information, please tell me and I will provide.

**UPDATE 1:** At Journeyman Geek's request I added entries with the system's IP:

-image cut for privacy reasons-

It had no effect.

Comment: Is source target meant to be blank? It should have your system's IP address, right?

Comment: As I understood that's something that should be left blank, as it's something new from the latest firmware. I got this information from here: https://www.snbforums.com/threads/asus-rt-n66u-firmware-version-3-0-0-4-380-7266.37527/. They claim that the "source target" should just be left blank to allow any IP.

Comment: eh. try your system's IP

Comment: Tried it, updated question, but it did not help, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the wireless drivers being used on this computer were about 5 years old, and that Windows 10 had automatically installed some new, better, ones. Windows 8.1 was unable to do this so I had defaulted to my 5 year old drivers.

This turned out to be the problem and qBittorent is now a happy camper.